# Can't get javascript to redirect to another html page upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying tot get my javascript code to redirect to the Index.html page if the variable money is equal to 100. Here is the html form code:

```
<form id = "form"  action = "">
    <h1> Enter the amount of money you would like to spend on your next trip. </h1><br>

            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
              <input type="text" name="money" class="form-control">

            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick = "MoneyForTrip()">Show Trips</button>

            </form>
```

and the javascript:

```
var money;

function MoneyForTrip()
{
money = parseInt(
        document.getElementById('form').money.value);

    if (money == 100)
    {
        window.location="Index.html";
    }


    else
    {
        window.alert("Enter another number"); 
    }

}
```

Any idea how I can get it to redirect to Index.html if money is equal to 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
window.location.replace("Index.html")
```

or

```
window.location.href = "Index.html"
```

Also take a look at [this Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1).

Comment: Any idea if I should be leaving the action = "" in the form section? It only seems to work if I change this action to Index.html but then it will go to the page whether money == 100 or not.

Comment: if you set action in the form it will go there everytime regardless of if money == 100

Answer (score 1):

Use the submit event instead of button's click event:

```
var money;
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    money = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').money.value);

    if (money == 100){
        window.location="Index.html";
    }

    else{
        window.alert("Enter another number"); 
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xzjW3/

Answer (score 0):

try
    `<input type="text" name="money" id="moneyfortrip" class="form-control">`

```
var money;

function MoneyForTrip()
{
money = parseInt(
        document.getElementById('moneyfortrip').value);

    if (money == 100)
    {
        window.location="Index.html";
    }


    else
    {
        window.alert("Enter another number"); 
    }

}
```